# How to prevent R from trying to load mgcv

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I need to run 2 different scripts in R without restarting the session. In the first i use the package `mgcv`and in the second i need `gam`. I wrote a script which detaches and removes the package `mgcv` and installs and loads `gam`. 
But still after i want to run the gam() function I get an error telling me that `mgcv` was not found. Which I interpret as R looking for the `mgcv` package for installing it...

Here's a MWE:

```
    install.packages(paste(path.pkgs,'mgcv_1.8-7.zip',sep=''),repos=NULL)
    require(mgcv)
    ## FIRST SCRIPT ##

    detach(package:mgcv)
    remove.packages('mgcv')
    unloadNamespace('mgcv')

    require(gam)
    ## SECOND SCRIPT ##
    gam(as.formula(t.thr.fm),data=data)
```

which returns the error:

```
   Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
   cannot open file 'H:/data/Documents/R/R-3.1.3/library/mgcv/R/mgcv.rdb': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas instead of restarting the session?

EDIT:

The solution suggested by Floo0 using package::function is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can tell R to take a function from a specific package via this syntax:

```
package::function
```

So in your case (do not detach `mgtv`) and use

```
mgcv::gam(...)
gam::gam(...)
```

If the function is not exported in the namespace of the function you can also try `package:::function` with 3 `:`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, that there are several different scripts using the function in different versions. I would really not want to change the whole code in all the versions. However if there is no other option, i will have to do so :)